# Mapping incoming JSON to a class in spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm struggling to understand why I'm getting the following error when I call my spring boot end point

```
{
  "timestamp": 1489573322678,
  "status": 406,
  "error": "Not Acceptable",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException",
  "message": "Could not find acceptable representation",
  "path": "/quotes"
}
```

This is the request that I'm sending to the server

```
POST /quotes HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
tamid: 5
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 94370a3f-6165-106f-f27f-44a44093e0d5

{
    "test": "works"
}
```

I would like the incoming JSON request body to map to a java class I have defined. Here is the class.

```
@Embedded
public class QuoteVersion {

    private String test;

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public void validate() {
    }
}
```

I'm using the @Embedded annotation for use with a mongodb mapping library that I'm hoping is unrelated to the issue I'm facing

Here is the controller method

```
@RequestMapping(
    path = "/quotes",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    headers = "Accept=application/json",
    produces = "application/json"
)
public @ResponseBody QuoteStatus create (@RequestHeader(value = "tamid") String tamId,
                                         @RequestBody QuoteVersion firstQuoteVersion) {
    // final QuoteVersion firstQuoteVersion = this.quoteFactory.createQuoteVersion(incomingQuote);
    final User currentUser = User.getFromTamId(tamId);
    currentUser.can(Permissions.CREATE_QUOTE);
    firstQuoteVersion.validate();
    final Quote newQuote = new Quote();
    newQuote.addVersion(firstQuoteVersion);
    this.dataRepository.save(newQuote);
    QuoteStatus qs = new QuoteStatus(newQuote);
    return qs;
}
```

I'm guessing that Spring Boot for some reason does not understand how to map the incoming payload to the class I have defined but I have no idea how to fix the issue. Thanks in advance for any help you may have to offer.

Comment: please provide your request snapshot

Comment: @MU thanks. I have updated the question with the request.

Answer (score 1):

Spring clearly indicates this problem:

> HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException

This means that in your `content-type` header you provided the wrong information or made a syntactical mistake.  Try putting there something like `application/json`.

**Also**

Make sure the other end will accept it.  You currently only accepting requests with an `accept` header with value `application/json`.  I don't think that is what you want.

So either remove that requirement or add this header to the request.

Comment: Yeah, I think the same, but prefered to ask for request snapshot before placing an answer

Comment: Thanks for your replies but thats not the issue. Im setting content type. I have attached the request I'm making.

Comment: Well in that case it is the other end... updated answer.